# How to change the Title of the searchbar cancel button in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I want to change the title of the search bar cancel button to Offers .Is there any method to change the title of the cancel button .

Can any one giv me suggestions with sample code?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your main code:

```
-(IBAction)changeButtonTextid)sender{
    [button setTitle:@"Changed!"] ;
}
```

And this in your .h:

```
@interface ButtonViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}

- (IBAction)changeButtonTextid)sender;
```